# Hierarchical documentation in Sphix

Tags: python-sphinx, toctree

I am trying to generate a hierachical documentation in Sphinx.

I would like the following structure:

```
Introduction
Quick start
Weather API (one general page + 2 subpages)
  Temperature
  Humidity
Sky API (one general page + 3 subpages)
  Planets
  Stars
  Satellites
Future API (one page is enough for this)
```

Assuming that there is one file per each line in the above TOC what should I do to achieve this?

I tried to include one or more `.. toctree::` directives into the top index file, but the results seem to be quite random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a directory and file structure that aligns with the following `toctree` entries, but the actual file names are appended with the `.rst` suffix.

```
.. toctree::

    introduction
    quick_start
    weather_api/index
    weather_api/temperature
    weather_api/humidity
    sky_api/index
    sky_api/planets
    sky_api/stars
    sky_api/satellites
    future_api/index
```

We do this in a part of [Pyramid's documentation](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/pscripts/index.html), although we also globbing because the order of the files is not important. Your order appears to have importance, so listing them in your desired order is necessary.

Comment: And I assume I must use the proper heading styles in the file (say ### for level 1 in weather_api/index.rst, and === for level 2 in temperature.rst and humidity.rst)

Comment: You can do whatever you want, but... IMO, headings should be consistent throughout your documentation. Create a style guide and follow it. That said, the suggested heading levels are documented at: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#sections